# Google Analytics for LikeShop Goal Funnel

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, conversions, goal-tracking

I'm using [Dash Hudson's LikeShop](https://dashhudson.com/) feature for users to shop products in Instagram posts. When A user clicks an Instagram post in LikeShop, they are redirected to the E-comm website page of that product, where they can then add it to cart and checkout.

I Tried to set up a new Goal & Funnel in order to see which specific products are being bought via LikeShop, with the idea of the entrance point of the funnel being the product page that the user is redirected to from LikeShop.

The funnel doesn't seem to be working as no entrance points are showing.

Here is the three steps for the goal set up:

Step 1:

[image: Goal Setup: Step 1]

Step 2:

[image: Goal Setup: Step 2]

Step 3:

[image: Goal Setup: Step 3]

Does anyone know how to either a) Correctly setup up the funnel to show the product page the user is redirected to from LikeShop as the entrance point, or b) Another alternative way to find which specific products are referring the user to the product page from LikeShop.

Thanks!

Comment: I already see something wrong for Step 1, but can you include a FULL screen screenshot of the goal config page?

Comment: @nyuen I have added screenshots for each step of the Goal Setup process that makes up the full goal configuration. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have selected "Regular Expression" as the match type for the destination, the same match type is applied to all the steps of your funnel. This means that you need to use regular expressions for the Page fields. For step 1, you also should not have the hostname (ie. `http://likeshop.me`) as GA only looks at the page path (not hostname). So steps 2 and 3 look correct, but note that they are "non-greedy" regexes, so a step like `/checkout/cart` will also accept `/checkout/cart/something` or `/checkout/cart/blahblah`. If you want to accept ONLY `/checkout/cart`, then you need to add `$` at the end to indicate the end of the string (ie. `/checkout/cart$`).

Comment: So then I could still use the page path from LikeSop (everything after http://likeshop.me) as the first step? Is this how I would know these customers came from like shop.